# Laravel helpers - removing the facade

Tags: laravel-5, methods, static-methods, helper

I have a file called \App\Helpers, which contains a couple of functions one it to check if the user is an admin

```
@if(\Helper::isAdmin())
  do something
@endif
```

I could add a method to the user model and get

```
$user->isAdmin()
```

This is a bit neater. However, is there any way just to do

```
@if(isAdmin())
      do something
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating a file with some global functions in it, so for example, add an entry in your `composer.json` file like one given below:

```json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers/functions.php"
    ]
},
```

Notice the `files` section. then create a top level directory inside your project root as `helpers` and create the `functions.php` file inside it and declare your global functions, for example:

```php
// helpers/functions.php
if (! function_exists('isAdmin')) {
    function isAdmin()
    {
        // You can entirely rewrite the logic here or
        // you can use your existing Helper::isAdmin()

        return \Helper::isAdmin();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` at last. Btw, if you are in `Larave 5.5.x` then you may use larave'ls new `Blade::if() Directives` [described here](https://laravel-news.com/bladeif).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not on 5.5 as that is really nice.